# Fractional derivatives in physics?

Tags: mathematical-physics, differentiation

[Fractional deriatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus) are interesting and all, but are there and scenarios in physics (either confirmed or hypothetical) where fractional calculus is part of a model?

Comment: Turns out there are uses https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_quantum_mechanics.

Comment: In the field of statistical mechanics, non-equilibrium phenomena modeled at times by fractional calculus, for example-http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370157300000703

Comment: Fractional Laplacians arise in field theories given by scaling limits of spin systems like Ising with long-range interactions. See these recent articles: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0550321315003703 , http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1751-8121/aa8099/meta Also note that for any scalar CFT one can define an osculating free theory which is Gaussian and has the same two-point function. These theories are typically described by fractional derivatives, i.e., fractional Laplacians because the scaling dimension of the scalar CFT field is rarely given by (d-2)/2